# How to change '\x??' to unicode in python?

Tags: python, encoding

I have a string:

```
\xe2\x80\x8e\xd7\x93\xd7\x9c\xd7\x99\xd7\xaa\xe2\x80\x8e
```

want to achange it to unicode using python

how do I do that?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? If Python 3, is it really a string or a `bytes` object?

Comment: python 2.7 is my version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That *is* UTF-8 data already; python is showing you the string literal form.

```
>>> print '\xe2\x80\x8e\xd7\x93\xd7\x9c\xd7\x99\xd7\xaa\xe2\x80\x8e'.decode('utf8')
‎דלית‎
```

The above line decodes the UTF-8 data to a `unicode` object with `.decode('utf8') and prints that; the`print`statement inspects the encoding used by my terminal and re-encodes the`unicode` object so that my terminal can display it properly.

You may want to read up on Python and Unicode:

- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky

Comment: The `.decode('utf8')` call in my code example does *exactly* that; it prints Unicode (with the python `print` statement converting it to my terminal encoding automatically).