# How to turn a mixed-formatted unicode string like "It\xe2\x80\x99s up to you. ¢ € £ ¥" into correct unicode? (python)

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

None of the answers I've come across seem to make sense, or at the least, I can't find out how to search for this issue.

I have a unicode string like this one:

```
It\xe2\x80\x99s up to you. ¢ € £ ¥ [
```

As you can see, it contains a mix of \x style unicode escaped characters, but it is already encoded into unicode. How do I turn it all into proper unicode characters (turning the \x characters into their native form).

Telling me what the \x format is called might help!

Answer (score 1):

The \x indicates a hexadecimal formatted number. This thread may help you with the conversion: [How to change '\x??' to unicode in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749145/how-to-change-x-to-unicode-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

It's a multi-step process, but it can all be combined on a single line:

```
>>> r'It\xe2\x80\x99s up to you. ¢ € £ ¥ ['.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'It’s up to you. ¢ € £ ¥ ['
```

The first `encode` converts all the Unicode characters to UTF-8 byte encoding.  The `decode` works on bytes, and `unicode_escape` specifically converts the `\xdd` sequences to a single character.  `encode('latin-1')` is a little trick to convert each Unicode character to the equivalent byte value.  Finally `decode('utf-8')` converts all the bytes back to characters, whether they were generated by the first `encode` or the second one.

This only works if the encoded bytes are actually UTF-8 as they were in this case.